# Orthogonal Complement with Bilinear Map over Different Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let $\tau:W\times V \rightarrow K $ be a bilinear map where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $K$.

Then, let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ and define $S(U) = \{w \in W\ |\ \tau(w,u)=0\ \forall u \in U\}$

My question is this:

Prove that $U \subset S(S(U))$

Now, I have already managed to prove that $S(U)$ is a subspace of $W$.

It seems to me that $S(S(U)) = \{w \in W\ |\ \tau(w,x)=0\ \forall x \in S(U)\}$ but this seems to get me in trouble because we're dealing with a set containing elements of $W$ not $U$.

If someone could persuade me that the following is true, then I think I can finish the proof from there:

$S(S(U)) = \{u \in U\ |\ \tau(u,x)=0\ \forall x \in S(U)\}$

Thanks for any help in pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the author skipped the "and analogously for $E \subset W$" part and that led to confusion.

Let's modify the notation a little: for $U \subset V$, define

$$S_W(U) := \left\lbrace w\in W : \bigl(\forall u\in U\bigr)\bigl( \tau(w,u) = 0\bigr) \right\rbrace,$$

and for $Z \subset W$, define analogously

$$S_V(Z) := \left\lbrace v\in V : \bigl(\forall z\in Z\bigr)\bigl( \tau(z,v) = 0\bigr) \right\rbrace.$$

Then your task is to show that for all $U\subset V$ you have

$$U \subset S_V(S_W(U)).$$